# C#, WPF, Отображение параметра "Версия сборки" в программе

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте! А не подскажите как отобразить внутри программы версию текущей сборки. Просто мне нужно выводить её в текстовом файле после запуска программы, а в Google я нигде ничего не нашёл.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Получить версию текущей сборки можно следующим образом:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Свойство `Version` имеет тип [System.Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Или

```
Assembly.LoadFile('имя_сборки').GetName().Version
```

Подробнее о `Assembly` можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Только вот `LoadFile` не кажется мне хорошей идеей: зачем грузить уже загруженную сборку, причём обходя кэш?

Comment: @VladD обходя который кэш?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Загруженных сборок. Сборка загрузится повторно несмотря на то, что она уже загружена.

Comment: @VladD, согласен, второй вариант избыточен.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, а может и нет. Перепроверю позже.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Не, в этом случае повторная загрузка не происходит. Странно.

Comment: @VladD В случае ASP.NET кэш действительно есть. При обновлении содержимого bin IIS копирует сборки куда-то во временный каталог и потом грузит оттуда. Если сделать LoadFile, то загрузится сборка из bin, а не из кэша, да еще и файл залочится при этом.

Comment: @kmv: Ого, не знал, спасибо!